# Blazor Server-Side: Role specific [Authorized] view with shared [NotAuthorized] view

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, claims-based-identity, blazor-server-side

I stumbled upon a little problem within my blazor server-side application in which I have the following base:

- I've developed an application using `<AuthorizeView>` for customer access.
- Landing page and everything is parked within the `<NotAuthorized>` area
- After login (by a consumer card) the customer is claim based authorized and the `<Authorized>` area is accessible

Business as usual so far I guess ...

Now I'll have to change my application to allow also operators to have a seperate access to the application with different functions, so I did the following:

- I've added a `ClaimTypes.Role` claim to my `ClaimsIdentity` which contains role `customer` for customers and role `operator` for operators
- I've added the `Roles` attribute to my `<AuthorizeView>`

Now I'm wondering, does anyone know if it's possible to share the `<NotAuthorized>` area for both roles because I am not able to add a `Roles` attribute to the area itself ... its just possible for the `<AuthorizeView>` in general.

The thing is, I just want to adjust my `<Authorized>` area according to the `Role` claim of the authenticated user without copying my `<NotAuthorized>` code to another `<AuthorizeView>`

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Epanalepsis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the  tags, you can do procedural logic by injecting the SignInManager - try this out and see if it works for you!

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager


@if (SignInManager.Context.User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    <p>AdminHTML here</p>
} 
else if (SignInManager.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>Some HTML here</p>
}
else
{
    <p>Not authorized goes here.</p>
}
```

More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#procedural-logic) on Microsoft's docs, however the method they used did not work for me in a standard Blazor page, which is why I used the SignInManager, this method seems to work well for me.